# Can I use coefficients of one set of regressions as dependent variable in a new regression?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics

Let's take CAPM model in finance as an example. I have stock prices of $N$ different companies. First, I do regression below and obtain betas of each company $i$.

$$Price=a+\beta_i*Index$$

Now I am curious about what company characteristics affect $\beta$. Can I then use $\beta$s from the first stage as the new dependent variable and regress against other variables? Why I can and why not? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is the classical Fama–MacBeth regression, see wiki page for references and a brief explanation:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fama%E2%80%93MacBeth_regression#:~:text=The%20Fama%E2%80%93MacBeth%20regression%20is,across%20time%20(panel%20data)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fama%E2%80%93MacBeth_regression#:%7E:text=The%20Fama%E2%80%93MacBeth%20regression%20is,across%20time%20(panel%20data)).